# Ajax call parameter field showing twice when going to php file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, ajaxform

Ive searched on here and could not find anything regarding this specifically.

The problem I am running into here is that the payload the ajax is hauling is being duplicated within itself. Along with this I find that the server is redirecting this request based on the 302 given below. PAY NO ATTENTION TO THE favicon.ico. THIS IS NOT THE PROBLEM.

[image]

As you can see, in the first call its the right field name and data. Then in the second it adds a ? and rewrites it.

Below is the actual data it passing and what I am talking about.

[image]

Why is this happening? Please look at code below regarding my ajax call.

```
var x='2020-06-19';
$.ajax({
    'url' : '//my file to php',
    'type' : 'GET',
    'headers':{'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    'data': {'field1': x},
    'success' : function(data) {  
    //logic
    },
    'error' : function(request,error)
    {
        console.log("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

Could it be because of the content type? Im having to do it this way to get around server CORS.

For imvain: `Request: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"<html>\r\n<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n","status":405,"statusText":"error"}`

Comment: This could be a problem with a `htaccess` mod rewrite

Comment: so how would i go by fixing this/working around it? @imvain2

Comment: I would say by fixing the problem with your `htaccess` is the best solution. But since that isn't posted, I don't know. A possible work around could simply be submitting your ajax as a POST, but that is a guess since you didn't post your htaccess.

Comment: after changing the GET to a POST, I now get the error above

Comment: I'm sure this is something server side now. Because your server is blocking a standard `post` and your `get` does a redirect. So it is difficult to really get into what could be causing this. I would start with your htaccess.